# Removing an application from the recent app list

Tags: android

I want to disable my app from the recent apps list, I don't want to remove the app I just want to disable it from recent apps list.How can I do this?

this is my code

```
<activity
   android:name=".Your_Root_Activity_Name"
 android:excludeFromRecents="true"
 .... 
</activity>
```

I have used above code in my manifest but it remove my app from recent app.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not have a concept of apps being disabled in the overview screen (recent apps list). There is no means via the Android SDK of doing what you want. `android:excludeFromRecents` is the closest thing, which as you note blocks that activity from appearing in the overview screen.

Comment: I have resolved my issue just by add this in my root activity ::   getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether i got your question or not, but the thing which i understood is you do not want to memorize the activity in stack when going to back to previous activity....
If this is what you want then just include the property in the activity tag with in AndroidManifest. `android:noHistory="true"`

```
<activity
      android:name=".registration.MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:noHistory="true"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Comment: thanks I have resolved my issue just by add this in my root activity :: getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);